# getting an HDInsight tools exception while accessing cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I'm working on a HDInsight cluster (type:Hadoop) created through azure management portal. But I'm unable to access it (using visual studio 2013). I'm getting HDInsight tools exception which goes as follows:

Failed to get clusters:system.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object at Microsoft.WindowsAzureHDIStudio.Business.HDInsightHelper.GetSubscriptionContexts(IAzureAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) at Microsoft.WindowsAzureHDIStudio.UL.Common.HiveTaskHelper.GetHDInsightclusters(updateLabelDelegate updateLabel) at Microsoft.WindowsAzureHDIStudio.Business.HDIAzureNode.serverExplorer.HDINode.b_0()

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the Azure node in the Server Explorer and select Manage Subscriptions, do you see your HDInsight Subscription?  Are you an admin or coadmin on the HDInsight subscription?